# How to display two images on two UIImageViews one View Controller, UIImagePickerController's?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to pick images from phone library when I tap on two different UIImageViews and after selection, display them on two different UIImageView's,
but I when run the following code, the same image displays at two different UIImageViews, How can I fix it?
'''

```
extension SettingProfileViewController:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
           profilePhoto.image = image
            print("profile")
        }

        if let wallImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            wallpaperPhoto.image = wallImage
            print("wallpaper")
        }


        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelectProfilePhotoView))
        profilePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        profilePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

     let wallTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelectWallpaperImageView))
        wallpaperPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(wallTapGesture)
        wallpaperPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

 @objc func handleSelectProfilePhotoView(){
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController() //открывает галерею
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @objc func handleSelectWallpaperImageView(){
        let pickerCont = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerCont.delegate = self
        present(pickerCont, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you observe is that when the user taps on any of the image views (`wallpaperPhoto` or `profilePhoto`), the `UIImagePickerController` always uses `self` as its delegate. Then, when the user picks an image, the delegate cannot distinguish any more which image view originally was tapped.

You could simply add a weak optional variable indicating the "active" tapped image view, and then set only it's image. Also, you can reduce the tap handler to a single function with a *sender* argument, which is the image view the user tapped on, and set the `activeImageView`to this.

```
extension SettingProfileViewController:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    weak var activeImageView:UIImageView? = nil

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
           activeImageView.image = image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelect(_:))
            profilePhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            profilePhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

         let wallTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SettingProfileViewController.handleSelect(_:)))
            wallpaperPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(wallTapGesture)
            wallpaperPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    @objc func handleSelect(sender:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let sendingImageView = sender.view as? UIImageView else {
            print("Ooops, received this gesture not from an ImageView")
            return
        }
        activeImageView = sendingImageView
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController() //открывает галерею
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

// ...
```

Comment: Could you please explain more explicitly relative to my code? What and where exactly should I add to my code?

Comment: It gives me an error "Extensions must not contain stored properties", when I try to weak var activeImageView:UIImageView? = nil, and if I add it inside the class and I run the code, it gives me Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file on the line activeImageView.image = image

Comment: I see. You need to put the variable into the "main" class definition (`class SettingProfileViewController`), near to where the outlets are declared.

Comment: keeps giving an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003515400'

Comment: Sorry, my fault. `sender` is the gesture recognizer, so you need to access `sender.view` to get the image view that received the gesture. See my changed `handleSelect` function

Comment: thank you so much. I applied a little different approach, but the used your handSelect and it works.